# Items doesnt added to Cart (React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, shopping-cart

I'm using React and Redux for creating a shop website. I want to add items to the cart using redux, but cart items it's not getting added only showing an error:

GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/product/61db003374fe4392e3446ae3 404 (Not Found)
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404"

and I suppose the problem is maybe with ID in action but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Please help me out. Below is my code

```
// reducer
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const item = action.payload;

      const isItemExist = state.cartItems.find(
        (i) => i.product === item.product
      );

      if (isItemExist) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
            i.product === isItemExist.product ? item : i
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
// actions
import axios from 'axios';
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addItemToCart = (id, quantity) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`);

  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: {
      product: data.product._id,
      name: data.product.name,
      price: data.product.price,
      image: data.product.images[0].url,
      stock: data.product.stock,
      quantity,
    },
  });

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

```
// store
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import {
  productsReducer,
  productsDetailsReducer,
} from './reducers/productReducers';
import {
  authReducer,
  userReducer,
  forgotPasswordReducer,
} from './reducers/userReducers';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  productDetails: productsDetailsReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  forgotPassword: forgotPasswordReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

let initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
      : [],
  },
};

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Doesn't look that the issue in the client code. I can assume that the route/service is unavailable. Can you open the URL of the API endpoint just in the browser?

Comment: Nvm it was typo misstake... i wrote "api/v1/product" instead of "api/v1/products". Thank you anyway :D